# No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:post_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the issue I am having, Haven't been able to get around it. Now this happens while logging into the account. I haven't had this issue before til last night.
[image]

Here is my users_controller.rb,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit ]

  after_action :signed_in_after_register, only: :create 

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    if params[:search]
        @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
      else
        @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
      end
  end

  def dashboard 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end 

  def newsfeed
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == nil
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

  def nav
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
  def posts
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def welcome
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
  def show 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new  
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @post = Post.new(params[:post_id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
    redirect_to @dashboard_path unless @user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully created!' }
        format.json { render :profile, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    if @user == current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update(user_params)
          format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :profile, status: :ok, location: @user }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'You do not have permission to edit the profile of another user.'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""

    end
    def signed_in_after_register 
      session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :comments, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :age, :profile_picture, :post, :body)
    end
end
```

Heres my comments _form.html.erb,

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Write a comment!" %>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p> <%= f.submit %> </p>

<% end %>
```

And here is my routes.rb,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#welcome'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#login', :as => :login 

  get 'dashboard' => 'users#dashboard', :as => :dashboard

  post 'logging/user' => 'sessions#create'  

  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout 

  get 'about' => 'about'

  get 'newsfeed' => 'users#newsfeed'

  resources :users, except: :show
  get 'profile/:user_id' => 'users#show', as: :profile

  get 'location' => 'location#location' 

  resources  :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  get 'index' => 'posts#index'

  get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => :register

end
```

If you guys do need to see anymore code then just let me know, I will post it! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I did. That's what that form was.

Comment: if you go here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html and search for "If your resource has associations defined, for example", you will see an example of the syntax you are using. And it says that it will only work when(in your case) '@post' is an existing object(saved in the database), you will be adding a comment to that post. And what I can see in your code is that @post is a new object too.

Comment: Can you add the comments_controller.rb file, as that would appear to be where the issue lies, based on the short stack trace we can see from your screenshot. Also, a few more lines from your development.log might be helpful in showing more of the errors than the screenshot can show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to create a URL that looks like this: `/posts/:post_id/comments` by passing `form_for([@post, @comment])`. It's OK that `@comment` isn't saved to the database, but the `@post` you use *must already be saved to the database* because you can't create that URL without `@post` having an ID.

Once `@post` is saved, it'll have an ID, so you can generate the route: for example, `/posts/32/comments`.

Check your `dashboard.html.erb` file for where you're using `@posts` and rendering `comments/_form.html.erb`. You may have a `post` object available, and you should use it in your form instead: `form_for([post, @comment])`.

You'll probably also want to remove the `@post = Post.new` line from your `#dashboard` controller action.

Comment: Is there anyway you can explain a bit more? After doing what you said about removing the @post I get the following error on this url /posts/:post_id/comments, Couldn't find Post with 'id'=24